# google reseller api using oauth2

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, google-reseller-api

I am trying to create a php page that allows joe bloggs to sign up for a google apps account via our reseller account. I have looked at the new google reseller api and they recommend using oauth2, however this works by going to a page where the user has to log in to google to get authorisation to use the api.  (Obviously this won't work as joe bloggs might not even have a google account of any type)

I have looked at an api service account but this is not available for the reseller api.

Can anyone suggest how to access the reseller api without redirecting to the google login page

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you authenticate to an API, you are authenticating the user that is performing a particular action. In the case of the Reseller API, you need to authenticate as an admin on the reseller account and not as a user of the new domain - it is your reseller account that is creating the new domain.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth2 Services Accounts are indeed compatible with the Reseller API.